# Create random points over a line spatvector in R

Tags: r, vector, line, point

I have a spatVector composed of a single-line geometry that covers the entire road network of my study area.
I would like to create a set of N random points over this geometry. I know how to do it in QGIS but I want to do it in R since I have to iterate this process 1'000 times and I want to create a loop.

Do you know any function to do this?

EDIT
First of all, I read my line shapefile using:
`Road_network <- vect("path/to/file.shp)`
Then I converted it into an SF object:
`Road_network_SF <- st_as_sf(Road_network)`
And finally, I use both the `st_sample`, getting the following results:

```
Random_points <- st_sample(Road_network_SF, size = 1799)
 Random_points
Geometry set for 46350 features  (with 44694 geometries empty)
Geometry type: MULTIPOINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 4503139 ymin: 2504751 xmax: 4622797 ymax: 2613276
Projected CRS: ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe
First 5 geometries:
MULTIPOINT EMPTY
MULTIPOINT EMPTY
MULTIPOINT EMPTY
MULTIPOINT ((4503139 2574957))
MULTIPOINT EMPTY
```

and the `st_line_sample` function, getting the following error:

```
Random_points <- st_line_sample(Road_network_SF, n = 1799)
Error in st_line_sample(Road_network_SF, n = 1799) : 
inherits(x, "sfc_LINESTRING") non è TRUE
```

When I converted the spatVector to an sf object, this is what I get:

```
Road_network_SF
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 2 fields
Geometry type: MULTILINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 4500176 ymin: 2504157 xmax: 4626207 ymax: 2616041
Projected CRS: ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe
```

FURTHER EDIT
The workflow proposed by @Gregory work really good, my error was due to a problem with the road shapefile. I changed it and no further problems occurred, thank you!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See my answer for how this question can be made reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sample random points along a vector geometry (like roads) with `sf::st_sample()`, however the results might seem confusing depending on how you look at them. Here's a reproducible example.

```r
library(sf, quietly = TRUE)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tigris, quietly = TRUE)
#> To enable 
#> caching of data, set `options(tigris_use_cache = TRUE)` in your R script or .Rprofile.
library(ggplot2)

suppressMessages(
  roads <- roads(state = "NC",
                 county = "Mecklenburg")
)
set.seed(1)
rpoints <- st_sample(roads, size = 5)
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_sample assumes that they are
#> planar
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = roads, color = "grey") +
  geom_sf(data = rpoints, color = "black")
```

[image]

We see on the map that we have generated 5 random points, as intended. Surprisingly, if you examine the structure of the `rpoints` object you'll see that it is a multipoint of length 21672, which you might think is the number of points. However, all but 5 of them have empty geometries. The reason is that there is a geometry (empty for most) for each of the objects that makes up the roads vector.

```r
str(rpoints)
#> sfc_MULTIPOINT of length 21672; first list element:  'XY' num[0 , 1:2] MULTIPOINT EMPTY
head(rpoints)
#> Geometry set for 6 features  (with 6 geometries empty)
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: NA ymin: NA xmax: NA ymax: NA
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
#> First 5 geometries:
#> MULTIPOINT EMPTY
#> MULTIPOINT EMPTY
#> MULTIPOINT EMPTY
#> MULTIPOINT EMPTY
#> MULTIPOINT EMPTY
```

Here's how to get the real points out of there.

```r
rpoints <- rpoints[!st_is_empty(rpoints)]
rpoints
#> Geometry set for 5 features 
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -81.01691 ymin: 35.07471 xmax: -80.62246 ymax: 35.2948
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
#> MULTIPOINT ((-80.88764 35.2948))
#> MULTIPOINT ((-80.62246 35.18395))
#> MULTIPOINT ((-81.01691 35.07471))
#> MULTIPOINT ((-80.78909 35.12663))
#> MULTIPOINT ((-80.83055 35.16959))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: nope, it return many more geometries, like 50 thousand while I ask for 1000. Moreover, it says that most of the points are empty geometries..

Comment: I tried also the "st_line_sample" function, firstly converting the spatVector to an SF object with "st_as_sf".
However, when running the function I get this error: 
"Error in st_line_sample(Road_network_SF, n = 1799) : 
  inherits(x, "sfc_LINESTRING") non è TRUE"

Comment: Could you create a minimal working example for us?

Comment: I edit the original question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great explanation, now everything is much clear to me. However, I set a number of points equal to 1799 (the number I want), but I get only 1673 points. Do you know why this may occur?

Comment: I don't know why, and without being able to reproduce your data and code there's really no way for me to figure it out.

Comment: How could I share my data with you?

Comment: Best to create a new question that 1) reproduces the problem you're having, and 2) uses data that is available from a package (like tigris). If you can't recreate your problem with packaged data, you could try posting your data to a publicly accessible url. In general, questions should use the minimum possible amount of data and code to reproduce the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. The package reprex can help you ensure we can reproduce your results.